# Devise + Carrierwave problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, carrierwave

I'm developing an app with Rails 3.2.16 that uses Devise gem for user authentication and CarrierWave to let the users upload a profile picture. Right now I'm trying to upload this picture to Amazon S3 but to be honest I don't know what's going wrong with my code. I had a `/profile` route that points to `users#show`, there I have several for_for @user to edit the user basic info (like name, phone numbers, etc), user password and user profile picture. I followed  [this tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) to allow the users change his info without requiring the password and it's working for the basic info and passwords but not for the upload picture form. Here is my code:

view in app/users/

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { method: :put, multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
      <% if @user.profile_picture_url.nil? %>
        <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
          <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=sin+imagen" alt=""/>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.file_field :profile_picture %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :profile_picture_cache %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="margin-top-10">
    <%= f.submit "Change", class: 'btn green' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def update
  @user = current_user

  successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
    @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
  else
    # remove the virtual current_password attribute update_without_password
    # doesn't know how to ignore it
    params[:user].delete(:current_password)
    @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if successfully_updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      format.html { redirect_to profile_path, notice: 'Success' }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { redirect_to profile_path, alert: 'Error' }
    end
  end
end

private

def needs_password?(user, params)
  user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
    params[:user][:password].present?
end
```

in my devise user model: `mount_uploader :profile_picture, AvatarUploader`

config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region                 => 'us-west-2',
    :endpoint               => 'prestadiario.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'prestadiario'
  config.fog_public     = false
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: at my console i cannot see any error and in my running app I just receive the error from `format.html { redirect_to profile_path, alert: 'Error' }`

Comment: Which rails version are you using? If you are using Rails 4 then please share `devise_parameter_sanitizer` call from `ApplicationController`.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.16 and Ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Please share the `server log` for when you try to `update without password`.

Comment: this is the log: http://jsfiddle.net/39dTx/embedded/result/. the rest of the logs is the assets requests

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48106/discussion-between-ricbermo-and-kirti-thorat)

Comment: I am in the chat room.

Comment: Well, I've found something. I added an field_text with the user email and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why but I needed to add the current_password field in order to save the picture.